# Android Xml database

Tags: android, xml

Hi I'm having a problem with my xml file for my android app. It's spitting out this error

error: invalid start tag Category . . . here is the source code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Category>
<destination id="1" main_cat="Hotel">
        <timestamp></timestamp>
        <business_name><![CDATA[ Sugarland Hotel ]]></business_name>
        <alias><![CDATA[ Sugarland Hotel ]]></alias>
        <address><![CDATA[ Araneta Avenue ]]></address>
        <city><![CDATA[ Bacolod ]]></city>
        <subcategory><![CDATA[ Hotel ]]></subcategory>
        <cuisine><![CDATA[ Italian,Asian ]]></cuisine>
        <budget> </budget>
        <features> </features>
        <working_days><![CDATA[ Everyday ]]></working_days>
        <opening><![CDATA[ 24/7 ]]></opening>
        <ending>    </ending>
        <contact><![CDATA[ (34)435-2690 , (34)435-2780 ]]></contact>
        <fax><![CDATA[ (34)435-2645 ]]></fax>
        <email><![CDATA[ rooms@sugarlandhotel.com ]]></email>
        <website><![CDATA[ www.sugarlandhotel.com  ]]></website>
        <payment_type><![CDATA[ cash,credit card,master card, visa ]]></payment_type>
        <lat><![CDATA[ 10.6524789N ]]></lat>
        <long><![CDATA[ 122.9372838E ]]></long>
        <desc><![CDATA[ Experience a modern hacienda retreat that nurtures the charm and romance of old world plantation living. Extensively renovated beginning 2010, Sugarland hotel unvails a celebrated balance of nostalgia and contemporary style, Capturing its original southern elegence, luxury, and decadence. Machuca tiles form cool geometric patterns in the hallways. Hacienda hardwoord floors contrast modern furnishings and amenities in the dramatic suits. The sugarland lifestyle offers guests the finest sensory indulgences: signature hacienda service, soothing organic toiletries, heirloom recipes, and unmatched privacy and tranquility. ]]></desc>
        <image>     </image>
</destination>
   </Category>
```

also i tried testing **CDATA** would i rather use it or go with xml schema. Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the whitespace in front of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`.  *Nothing* can appear before it.

Both IntelliJ and my browser say your XML is fine.  There must be something else wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that its an error in my posting in my codes there is no white space.

Comment: yeah i also tried from a xml validator my xml has no error . . idk why my android app is failing.

Comment: If I read correctly, Android is using the SAX and DOM parsers that are built into Java.  Those work fine, so it's something else that you're doing.